# Distinct Values in Array in PLSQL

Tags: arrays, plsql, associative-array

I want to store distinct values from a column present in a table into array. I am getting below error. How can I achieve this?

```
select count(distinct(Name)) into n from table;      

create or replace type array_type is varray(100) of varchar2(20); 

for i in 1 .. n loop
    name_array.extend;
    select distinct(Name) into name_array(i) from table order by name asc;
end loop;   

Error :
 ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

Table :

[image]

Comment: Could you provide array definition?

Comment: create or replace type array_type is varray(100) of varchar2(20);

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. Putting the column next to it between parentheses doesn't change anything. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` just like `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,b`

Comment: Why a `for` loop at all? `select distinct name bulk collect into name_array from the_table;` would be way more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `SELECT DISTINCT value BULK COLLECT INTO` to get distinct values and store them into an collection.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  city VARCHAR2(250)
);

INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('A', 'X');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('B', 'Y');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('A', 'Z');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('C', 'K');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('D', 'P');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('A', 'Q');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('D', 'R');
INSERT INTO test_table (name, city) VALUES ('C', 'S');

COMMIT;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_type IS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(20);

DECLARE
  v_name_array array_type := array_type();
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT NAME
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO v_name_array
    FROM test_table
   ORDER BY NAME ASC;
  -- Show resulting values in collection
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_name_array.count
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(v_name_array(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention few points here before you discuss about the solution

**Point 1 :- Hope you understand the error ORA-01422.**

when you use select into it always expects a single row to be fetched which is clearly not the case with your example

Cause: The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.

Action: Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

**Point 2 :- Usage of cursor**

you use the same cursor one time to count and the second time to fetch. why cant declare it one time and just use it once to loop and fetch or use a for loop instead

e.g - for i in (select distinct(Name) from table order by name) loop

**Point 3 :- Usage of type**

I would suggest to create the type locally instead of creating as an object in database unless until you want to reuse it in many places. forget to mention watch out for the index you used to store the value. i don't question why you used **"of varchar(20)"** but you can give it a thought.

**Point 4 :- Normalization**

Just as a suggestion , think about the normalizing the database. if you look to your example data you will realize its redundant data which we need to avoid.

**Point 5 :- Usage of bulk collect**

As mentioned in one of the answer its always better to use bulk collect with collections but yes if the data set you are dealing with is not huge you may not go for bulk collect and just use the simple loop to put the data into it.

Finally if try to make the code correct in your case ( assuming the type we created in the database), I would do something like below.

```
DECLARE
   n NUMBER;
   --local variable is also fine here for type in case you changed your mind not to create in db
   --type array_type is varray(100) of varchar2(20);
   name_array array_type := array_type();
   idx NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
   -- default order is ASC , so we can omit the same in real query
   FOR i IN (SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) NAME FROM teststack ORDER BY NAME)
   LOOP
      name_array.extend;
      name_array(idx) := i.name;
      idx := idx + 1;
   END LOOP;
   FOR i IN 1..name_array.count LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(name_array(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```